# how to version files ONLY locally with git

Tags: git, egit, tortoisegit

I have a project with two branches `foo` and `baar`. In this project I have a config files `database1.properties` and `database1.properties` where data base properties are stored for example schema name and schema password. When I am working on foo branch, schema name is foo and password is foo and when I am working on baar branch schema name is baar and password is baar. How to tell git that these properties files are only for my local system and shouldn't be pushed to the origin repo? I use egit and also tortoiseGit.

Comment: Perhaps you should have cloned locally the project...

Comment: Maybe just don't add them with `git add`

Comment: And add them to .gitignore

Comment: @EdwardBlack but the properties files are different for both branches. I would like when I switch to the other branch, that the right properites files are checked out so I have to commit them

Comment: @SergeyEremin if I add them to .gitignore I can not version them. database.properties contains contains login data for foo branch which are different from the login data for baar branch. So this is why I can't add them to .ignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a single branch you cannot prevent selected files from being pushed.

When branch is getting pushed, all commits will be pushed to the remote.

As a workaround you could have your changes(specific to local) in a different branch(`foo-local`, `bar-local` etc) and whenever you want these changes in local system, use `git merge local-branch --no-commit --no-ff` or similar command to merge into actual branch (This will not merge your local specific changes to the remote tracking branch). Once you are done, you can discard these changes(however these changes will always be there in local branch and can apply to actual branch any time you want).

Answer (score 1):

## Way 1 - Rebase continuously

Suppose there are 3 branches:

- `master` for public
- `boo` for private
- `baar` for private

Something like this:

[image: The 2 branches]

You developed something on `master` branch, then rebase the foo and baar branch on master. You need (1)Checkout `foo`, (2)Rebase `foo` onto `master`, (3)Checkout `baar`, (4)Rebase `baar` onto master, then it will become:

[image]

**Note**: have to repeate those steps again and again.

## Way 2 - Merge

Suppose the same 3 branches.

Checkout `foo`, and merge `master` into `foo`:

[image]

Do the samething on `baar` branch, and finally you will get:

[image]

After developed some on master, do those steps again, and get:

[image]

## Way 3 - submodule

The above 2 ways is a little bit dangerous, if you push all branch to remote. This way is more complex, you need to know how to use submodule, but I like it more. :)

(1) Prepare a data repo for private data base, you can checkout the branch between `foo`/`baar`.

[image]

[image]

(2) Prepare another normal/simple repo as a container, something like this:

[image]

[image]

(3) Then add that data repo as a submodule into this repo:

[image]

You will get these after commit:

[image]

[image]

(4) Again, add the public repo, named `test` here, as a submodule:

[image]

[image]

For now, you can develop in that `test` repo, and checkout whatever branch of data repo on the other side.

**Note 1**: Require to adjust path well.

**Note 2**: if you don't like submodule, you could just use a folder as container, then put those two repo into it.

## Way 4 - Merge with no commit or squash

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35863035/3247152)(by @Royal Pinto) said, I show the TortoiseGit operation here.

[image]

[image]

Note: the private data has been staged into index file. So that the next commit command will commit it into repo.